# An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netlogon

On my main 2008 R2 domain controller:

When I boot, the screen goes black (monitor light goes amber)

RDP logon to the server says "An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started"

Trying to logon to the local admin account on the domain controller via RDP gives the same problem.

It's a really big mess..

EDIT: After playing around with some remote management tools, it seems neither netlogon nor RPC server are running.. tried starting them but they won't start..

Comment: Domain Controllers don't have local user accounts.

Comment: @joeqwerty Splitting hairs, but [Directory Services Restore Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776568(v=ws.10).aspx) *does* auth Administrator logon against the local SAM database, not DS.

Comment: @jscott True enough, but I don't think that's what the OP meant.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes it is

Comment: My apologies to both of you then.

Comment: How are you accessing DSRM via RDP?

Comment: @joeqwerty [2008 Allows for Remote DSRM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794729(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Not to belabor this point, but why would you want to run DSRM for this problem? Regarding your edit, can you remotely access the Event Logs? I'm guessing not but if you can that may give you some clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just nuking the server

Answer (score 1):

> On my main 2008 R2 domain controller:

Luckily for you, there's no such thing as a main domain controller. They're all peers, and some just hold more roles than others.

It sounds like your server has some serious issues and you haven't provided any meaningful details for us to help resolve them, so I'll recommend this: Remove all FSMO roles from this DC. Demote it (or do a metadata cleanup if you can't demote it) so that it's no longer a Domain Controller. Reinstall it and dcpromo it again.

It's better to just rebuild a wonky DC than to mess with it, considering how modular they are.

Comment: Lol I nuked the server over 2 months ago.

Comment: Welp, sounds like we came to the same conclusion :) If you solve your own problem, it's encouraged that you post it as an answer to your own question. Once a question has an "accepted" answer, (i.e. you click the green check mark next to one) it won't get bumped to the front page periodically.

Comment: Didn't know about the bumping - I spend most of my time on stackoverflow so I do not check this place much.

Answer (score 1):

you have to start "Netlogon" service 
so follow the path : "Control Panel\Administrative Tools\services"
then find the service named "Netlogon" and double click on this service
int the "startup type" choose "manual"
on "service status" click start

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Netlogon service to automatic and restart the server.

1. Click on Administrative tool ->> services ->> double click on Netlogon.
2. Change the startup type to automatic.
3. Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try Entering the Following Command in CMD with **Admin Rights**

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, how it feels when domain controller doesn't work up to the mark.

As you have tried all remote access tools, assuming RSAT also, but to no purpose.

Therefore, I would suggest if you have any RODC in your domain, just seize (FSMO) 5 roles.  You have to run ntdsutil command on RODC.

Convert your RODC to DC.

http://kpytko.pl/active-directory-domain-services/seizing-fsmo-roles/

Regards.
Sairam